# When copy & pasting text with apostrophe it is not passing through mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, apostrophe

I have added `mysql_real_escape_string()` with a query for text inputs. When a user writes text with symbols it passes through `mysql_real_escape_string()` and works fine, but when the user pastes text copied from other websites it won't pass through `mysql_real_escape_string()`. The text after the apostrophe is cut off.

How can I fix this?

I believe when user pastes text in input field it's not in UTF-8 encoding. Is there any way to process it without errors in core PHP? Also please tell me if you have solutions in Pear DB.

Comment: Is the text getting cut off or are there errors? If there are errors, what are they?

Comment: You really should show more code. `mysql_real_escape_string` should handle any escaping needed.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming users may also paste URL encoded text, so use [urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode) function in PHP. That could be one of the possible cases. Another one is as you said UTF-8, in that case use MySQL's [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) function. I hope this helps. If possible please provide more details like for what texts you are getting this problem.